# Multiplication modulo $n$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I encountered the following basic encryption scheme while studying MIT OCW's [6.042](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/) course:

> 1. Exchange a public prime $p$ and a secret prime $k'$.
> 2. Encryption: Compute $m'=rem(mk, p)$
> 3. Decryption:
>
>    i) Compute $k^{-1}$ such that $kk^{-1}=1\pmod n)$
>
>    ii) Now $m'=rem(mk,p)\equiv mk \pmod p$
>
>    $\implies m'k^{-1}\equiv mkk^{-1} \pmod p$
>
>    $\implies m'k^{-1}\equiv m \pmod p$    <--(How?)

I do not understand the last step. How is $kk^{-1} = 1$ ? We have only been taught the basic properties of modulo and I derived the above relation as follows:

> Given $kk^{-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$
>
> $m'\equiv mk \pmod p$
>
> $\implies m'.(kk^{-1}) \equiv mk.1 \pmod p$ [$a\equiv b \pmod n, \space c\equiv d \pmod n \implies ac\equiv bd \pmod n$]
>
> $\implies m'k^{-1} \equiv m \pmod p$ [Since $gcd(k,p) = 1$]

Is my method correct, or is there any other way to derive the relation ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have $m'\equiv mk \pmod p$. Multiply both sides by $k^{-1}$ to get $m' k^{-1} \equiv mk k^{-1} \pmod p$.

On the other hand you have $kk^{-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$. Multiply both sides by $m$ and you get $m kk^{-1}\equiv m \pmod p$.

You end up with $m' k^{-1} \equiv mk k^{-1} \equiv m  \pmod p$